# Primefaces Button submit entire page unexpected

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 6.x and JSF 2.x

I have a 'breadCrumb' and then I have put a CommandButton for 'Options' facet.

I'm seeing the button is generated with 'type=submit' instead of 'type=button' and cuz of it the form is getting submitted when the button is click.

Could you please advice why it is happening like that?

If I put the button outside of breadcrumb, the button is rendered as expected.

Thanks,

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your button wrapped by a form in both cases? Maybe this makes the difference.

To explicitly reduce the processing to the given button, you can set its `process` attribute:

```
<p:commandButton ... process="@this" />
```

See also:

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for adding the reference.